# Android Service Client communication best appraoch

Tags: java, android

I have a bound service which do some async tasks, once the task is finished the service calls the registered listener, I'm wondering if this is approach has any flaws or if there is better way to do it.

**SomeService**

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
public void doSomeTask(OnTasksFinishListener listener) {
final OnTasksFinishListener _listener = listener;
   new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // some extensive code
                handler.post(new Runnable(){
                    public void run() {
                        _listener.onTaskFinish();
                    };
                });
            }
        }.start();

}
```

**Client**

```
mLocalService.doSomeTask(this);

public void onTaskFinish(){
    //something will happen in the UI.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is fine, but I would simplify it by using `android.os.AsyncTask`.